# How to structure a conversation in html, as in a novel?

Tags: html, semantics, dialog

A dialogue between 2 guys, in a novel :

― Hello, said John. How are you?
― Fine, said Jack.
― Cool !

What is the best semantic practice for this representation in HTML5, please ?

```
<dl>
    <dt>...</dt>
    <dt>...</dt>
    <dt>...</dt>
</dl>
```

or

```
<p class=first_quote>...</p>
<p class=inter_quote>...</p>
<p class=last_quote>...</p>
```

or others ?

Comment: there is no 'best' way. It's on developer how he choose to implement that. But I would recommend classes like your second example, just use span/div or something else rather paragraph tag p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose what you love!

See this : http://gabrieleromanato.name/how-to-mark-up-chats-and-conversations-in-html5/

Sure you can use odd , even css selectors to style it floating left and right like whatsapp style.